# Unable to locate OpenCV header, but pkg-config contains path

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, homebrew

In order to install OpenCV on my Mac, I opted to use `brew install opencv` instead of building from source as is specified in the Mac installation tutorials. Homebrew's installation path appears to be /opt/homebrew, and all of the included packages that I have downloaded appear to be contained in the include in that directory.

I wrote a sample program program in order to test the installation:

```
#include <opencv4/opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv4/opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv4/opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main() {
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    Mat img;
    
    while (1) {
        cap.read(img);
        imshow("Image", img);
        
        if (waitKey(1) == 27) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And, to compile it, I ran:

```
g++ video.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4`
```

which returned:

```
fatal error: 'opencv4/opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp' file not found
```

I ran `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4` to check whether it was set correctly, and the following was returned:

```
-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/include/opencv4 -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib -lopencv_gapi -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_alphamat -lopencv_aruco -lopencv_bgsegm -lopencv_bioinspired -lopencv_ccalib -lopencv_dnn_objdetect -lopencv_dnn_superres -lopencv_dpm -lopencv_face -lopencv_freetype -lopencv_fuzzy -lopencv_hfs -lopencv_img_hash -lopencv_intensity_transform -lopencv_line_descriptor -lopencv_mcc -lopencv_quality -lopencv_rapid -lopencv_reg -lopencv_rgbd -lopencv_saliency -lopencv_sfm -lopencv_stereo -lopencv_structured_light -lopencv_phase_unwrapping -lopencv_superres -lopencv_optflow -lopencv_surface_matching -lopencv_tracking -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_datasets -lopencv_text -lopencv_plot -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_viz -lopencv_wechat_qrcode -lopencv_xfeatures2d -lopencv_shape -lopencv_ml -lopencv_ximgproc -lopencv_video -lopencv_dnn -lopencv_xobjdetect -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_xphoto -lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core
```

I think that this implies that the path to OpenCV is set for linking the package during compilation, so I was wondering about why the linker couldn't find it. Also, my end-goal is to write a program involving pcl, and I also installed pcl via brew. Since it is also contained in opt/homebrew/, do I have to create a specific reference to its path outside of /usr/ when making the cake file? Thanks!

Comment: I think `opencv4/opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp` needs to be `opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp`

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yep. | Also, OP, get rid of those `using namespace` lines before you shoot yourself in the foot. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Alan Birtles. It was just a problem with my includes. For those reading, `#include <opencv4/opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>`, as well as all of the other OpenCV packages, had to refer directly to OpenCV2. So, for example, it had to be `#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>`

Answer (score 0):

We have opencv4 installed to a custom location and don't use the pkgconfig tools to maintain it. I combined the above answers to resolve the issue by creating a pkgconfig file, setting the env variable in my .bashrc, and then verifying with pkg-config. This resolved my opencv build for a rust cargo .toml file that specified `opencv = "0.86.1"` in the dependencies section.

Output of running `cat /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/opencv.pc`. Note a small difference that only has one include dir; this was required for the rust build of opencv because it was getting an error of an include path that wasn't found or was empty.

```
prefix=/usr
exec_prefix=${prefix}/local
includedir=${prefix}/include/opencv4
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib

Name: opencv2
Description: The opencv library
Version: 4.5.5
Cflags: -I${includedir}
Libs: -L${libdir} -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_core -lopencv_ml -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_flann -lopencv_video -lopencv_highgui
```

In my `.bashrc` file:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

Output of running `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`

```
-I/usr/include/opencv4 -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_core -lopencv_ml -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_flann -lopencv_video -lopencv_highgui
```